# Package installation in salt-stack including --allow-unauthenticated

Tags: authentication, package, salt-stack

During deployment, I am trying to install a package.
It works fine on some environment and does not work on others.
I added a flag, that will get the value True when I'm on one of the problematic environments, and I want it to add the tag `--allow-unauthenticated` when the flag is on, I found out that when I install it that way manually, the problem is solved, now I need to happen automatically.

This is the command that makes it work proparly when installing manually:

```
sudo salt <minion name> cmd.run "sudo apt-get -y --allow-unauthenticated install zabbix-agent"
```

This is the package installation during deployment:

```
zabbix-agent-installed:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: zabbix-agent
    - zabbix-agent: '>=4.0.0'
    - ignore_epoch: True

    <Add here>:
    {% if flag == 'True' %}
    - ** allowing unauthenticated syntax **
    {% endif %}

    - require:
      - pkgrepo: zabbix-agent-repo-added
```

what is the right way to do it there?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `skip_verify` option?

```
    - skip_verify: True
```

> skip_verify (bool) -- Skip the GPG verification check for the package to be installed
>
> --allow-unauthenticated
>              Ignore if packages can't be authenticated and don't prompt about it.

If that doesn't work, then you need to convert the pkg.installed state into a cmd.run state so that you can give the extra arguments for apt-get.

I should add that skipping verification checks is dangerous and you should fix the cause of the verification failures instead of skipping the check.